# Function returns an error (ESLint) move function to body root

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have the following function.the code does what i need it to do,however its not structured correctly because of the declarations therefore it gives "(ESLint) move function to body root" error :

This is my code:

```
function onSuccess(result) {

            if (result) {
                 function GetTotal(result) {

                    var totBal = 0;
                    var str = 'R';
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                        totBal += result[i].Price;
                    }
                    str += totBal.toFixed(2);
                    return str;
                }
                var span = document.getElementById("Total");
                span.innerHTML = GetTotal(result);
            }
        }
```

This is what i tried:

```
function onSuccess(result) {
        var fn;
        if (result) {
          fn=function GetTotal(result) {

                var totBal = 0;
                var str = 'R';
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    totBal += result[i].Price;
                }
                str += totBal.toFixed(2);
                return str;
            };
            var span = document.getElementById("Total");
            span.innerHTML = GetTotal(result);
        }
    }
```

the "(ESLint) move function to body root" gets solved But with the above it returns an error saying "getTotal is not defined"

Comment: Why define a function at all in such a limited scope?  Why not just perform the calculation directly?  You can't re-use the function anywhere, so you don't need the additional syntax of defining it.

Comment: Alternately, why not just move the function to the body root?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Then function declaration is on right hand side. It becomes a local variable to the variable on left hand side. Use the name `GetTotal` instead of `fn` in the main function scope.

```
function onSuccess(result) {
        var GetTotal;
        if (result) {
          GetTotal = function(result) {

                var totBal = 0;
                var str = 'R';
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    totBal += result[i].Price;
                }
                str += totBal.toFixed(2);
                return str;
            };
            var span = document.getElementById("Total");
            span.innerHTML = GetTotal(result);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just move the function to the body root as suggested by ESLint like so

```
function onSuccess(result) {
  function GetTotal(result) {
    var totBal = 0;
    var str = 'R';
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      totBal += result[i].Price;
    }
    str += totBal.toFixed(2);
    return str;
  }

  if (result) {
    var span = document.getElementById("Total");
    span.innerHTML = GetTotal(result);
  }
}
```

Or just get rid of the function as it's inside of a function anyway and you don't seem to be using it again.

```
function onSuccess(result) {
  if (result) {
    var totBal = 0;
    var str = 'R';
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      totBal += result[i].Price;
    }
    str += totBal.toFixed(2);
    var span = document.getElementById("Total");
    span.innerHTML = str
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On your second example the function is now inside the variable `fn`. You can access it by calling `fn()`. Another option is to rename the variable to reflect the function behavior and then call it by its new name.

```js
var fn;
fn=function GetTotal(result) {
  console.log('function called!');
}

fn();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simgply add rules to disable the eslint rule. I.E. add `"no-inner-declarations":[0, "always"],` in `.eslintrc.json`